# Can you combine windows to go and linux on a stick?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, boot, grub

**Background**

On my vocational training school there are 2 turns, and the morning ones always break the computers, so I started to carry a virtual machine on an hdd, in order to avoid problems (I have a stable system as long as virtualbox works), but a friend showed me that he boots directly to windows using windows to go (aparently installing directly to an usb hdd makes windows go crazy, crash and fail when switching machines), but being a school that primarily uses linux and open source software I need a linux, is it possible to do both on the same hdd?

**expected outcome**

an hdd with 3 partitions (windows, linux, swap) capable of booting both systems (maybe with grub?)
maybe a fourth to interchange files between OSes?

**what i tried**

I installed windows to go, no problem, but when I installed linux mint, it froze on boot, no grub, no windows loader, nothing

Comment: How can it freeze if there is no bootloader coming up or bootstrapping happening?